# Set a default value of an extjs 4.2 combobox using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, combobox, extjs4

I have a an extjs 4.2 combobox that I'm using to display some data. Now I'm trying that based on a condition the combo would display a default value. I managed to return the needed data based on that condition, however I'm failing to set the necessary value in the combobox. How am I supposed to set that specific value?

combo:

```
var locationStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'model_LOCATION',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'Record?DB=GEO&Table=LOCATION',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record:'record'
        }
    },
    autoLoad:true
});




var C_LOCATION= Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    name : 'C_LOCATION',
    id : '${DB}.${Table}.C_LOCATION',
    store : locationStore,
    queryMode : 'local',
    displayField : 'display',
    valueField : 'value',
});
```

AJAX call:

```
var data;
        var code = 111;
        data = "CODE ='" + code + "'";
        var text;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Record?DB=GEO&Table=LOCATION",
            dataType: 'xml',
            data: {
                "Where": data
            },
            success: function(xml) {
                 text = xml;
                Ext.getCmp('${DB}.GEO.LOCATION').setValue(text);
                   } 
                });
```

Comment: In your success method, what is the value of xml coming?

Answer (score 0):

Give the combo box a reference in the config section (`reference: 'comboBox'`). Then call `comboBox.setValue(defaultValueGoesHere)` in your function where you are getting the specific value. You may need to hunt down the comboBox reference depending where you are.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you will have to parse your XML response. Similar as in your code definition for the locationStore, where you specify the record in the xml response.

Why do you make the second ajax call? 
Could you not filter the locationStore based on the CODE value, instead?

Comment: this isn't really an answer as expands the question.

Comment: Why, I guess he has to parse his xml response to get the value - but as @Saloo commented, we would need to know what the xml response looks like.